# Hide Progress Bar for Add-RdServer

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Im trying to hide the progress bar of Add-RdServer.

I have tried using both *$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'* and *$global:progressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'* but the progress bar still shows.

Does anyone know how to successfully hide it?
I am using Powershell 5.1

Comment: some of the MS cmdlets from outside of the PoSh group are ... wildly non-compliant. [*sigh ...*] you may be able to work around that by redirecting the various streams until you find the one that is being used ... and then send that to `$Null`.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey I tried redirecting all of the streams but could still not find an answer for this. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: are you actually using a cmdlet named `Add-RdsServer`? the MSDocs site only shows `Add-RDServer` - note the _single letter 's'_.

Comment: Sorry it is Add-RDServer.i have updated the post

Comment: kool! [*grin*] i just thot of another possible way around it ... have you tried running that code in a Job? i think PS Jobs run in a non-interactive session & that would make the progress bar invisible.

Comment: I thought of something similar, which was to spin up a new hidden powershell session using start-process, with the runas verb, but that causes a new UAC window popup which the user has to accept, and I need to avoid that. I presume a PS Job would be the same, but I will give it a try tomorrow to be sure.

Comment: powershell Jobs & runspaces DO NOT have any interactivity. [*grin*] that means there is no console to display stuff ...